# How to print build logs in parallel if running build script from another shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, build-automation

How to print logs generated from another script which is executed from the script I am running  in parallel.

Basically I am running a script which runs another script to start a build, and I want to see the compilation logs in parallel as I can see it while running the build script directly.

Also can we print the time for how long a command is running in a shell script. Like I want to know how much time my build has taken so far.

PS : I am new to scripting and please redirect me if this is answered before in any thread as I am not able to find it in SO :)

Comment: Possible if you create a server. Perhaps a `db` also can do.

Comment: You mean like have half the screen showing the build and half showing the logs ? With time in the top right maybe ?

Comment: @Jidder:  yeah, actually I just need to see the build logs. These are 2 separate queries but if I can have time along with the build that would be great. Any suggestion how I can achieve it?

Comment: Where is the build script currently sending the output to?  stdout?  Also, apart from starting the build script, what else is the wrapper script doing?

Comment: Hi @RishabhSagar , the wrapper script just take some argument, based on the arguments and some variables, it starts the appropriate build script. The build logs are also redirected to another file which I can tail from another shell, but I want it in the same console. I am just trying to write a simple script which take the argument which build to start. The original build script works just fine with compilation logs.

Answer (score 0):

You could display your build script on the current screen by tailing the logs from it.

test2.sh (build script)

```
#!/bin/bash
#test2.sh

# Save start time of script
startTime=$SECONDS

# Save outputs to log
echo "line 1" > /tmp/log
sleep 2
echo "line 2" >> /tmp/log
sleep 2
echo "line 3" >> /tmp/log
sleep 2
echo "line 4" >> /tmp/log

# Calculate total elapsed time in seconds
echo "Elapsed seconds: $(($SECONDS - $startTime))" >> /tmp/log
exit 0
```

test.sh (run time script)

```
#!/bin/bash
#test2.sh

echo "Starting test2.sh"
sh test.sh &
scriptPid=$!

# tail the build script logs. Exit on $scriptPid
tail -n0 -F --pid=$scriptPid /tmp/log 2>/dev/null

wait $scriptPid
exit 0;
```

Now just run test.sh to display the output logs from test2.sh